# Problems in terminal

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

after I pasted these lines in terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta1 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qt5-meta-full && echo 'export PATH=/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc`

It asks for my sudo password. I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 4):

Well, type your user password. It will not show you the password when you are typing for security reasons but after you finish typing the password and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the whole terminal line should work.

The **user password** is the password you use to login to Ubuntu and the one that it was set up when Ubuntu was installed.